# Linux: Conditional Auto-Login --- Wake on Lan alarm clock

Tags: linux

I'm making a Wake-On-Lan alarm clock, and I'm trying to have a script that will only auto-login a specific user given a specific condition (time-range, something before shutdown, etc...)

I know how to have a script run at boot-up with init-d, but I'm not sure how to have it perform a login. I read the man page for the login bin utility but it says it has to run in a login shell.

tl;dr : How do I login from an init.d script?

Thanks,
Syn

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking the wrong question.

I know what WOL is, but what's a WOL alarm clock?

Why does your script need to "log in"?  Are you trying to run a GUI app automatically after booting up?

Is this machine going to be woken up?  Or is it going to wake another machine up?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've found that there is an app called Music Player Daemon which should work out for me. It's supposed to be able to play music before a log in (as it has it's own user).

Comment: Unfortunately, it has some error at boot up and won't play... while once I'm logged in it works. The machine will be woken up by my router at the appropriate time using WOL. My machine will boot and run a script that checks the time(and/or)conditions. If the time (and/or) conditions are true it will begin to play music.